# Toggle Button in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

Is there a more efficient way to write the toggle for the isCollaped in this Vue3 component?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  const isCollapsed = ref(false)
</script>
```

Template:

```
<template>
  <button @click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    Button text
  </button>
<template>
```

Comment: No.  you could move the toggling to a method if you prefer less code in your template, but it's not any more or less efficient.

Comment: Using hooks help you manage common logic script like a toggle status controller

Comment: You could use a checkbox or a switch component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which you added in the post is already efficient but if it's about an alternate approach then you can just move the `toggle` logic into a separate method.

Script **:**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  const isCollapsed = ref(false)

  const toggleState = () => {
    isCollapsed.value = !isCollapsed.value;
  };
</script>
```

Template **:**

```
<template>
  <button @click="toggleState">
    Button text
  </button>
<template>
```